# leveling a bedframe on a slanted floor

Tags: repair, wood, flooring

All:
While I wait for my floor to cave and fall into the neighbor's house, I have an issue that I was hoping for some help with. I bought a bed for my back most recently, but the bed itself is tilted. The right side of the bed is up about 4 or so inches higher than the left side. This is a platform frame because of a memory foam mattress, so the posts are rectangular and square. There are three posts along the right side, 3 in the middle and 3 on the left side for a grand total of 9. I don't need to touch the posts on the right side as I don't want them higher and there's no way of lowering them, and I was thinking that simple wedges might be good for the three posts in the middle because I can just push them under to support the middle posts. My issue comes with the posts on the left side; the middle post measures 1/8 inches square, while the farthest posts measure 1 1/8 inches by 1/8 inches and is rectangular. I know it needs to come up about 4 inches and even if that's not exactly accurate it'd be much better than where it is now. I don't have many tools apart from a dremel so I wanted to try to avoid doing much to the posts. My initial thought was to request that a hardware store simply cut holes in a block of wood to those specifications and have the bottom of the hole be 4 inches up with another 3 inches to surround the post and make sure it would not slide, but I couldn't find a store willing to do this. They all wanted to sell me a few tools, but I'm totally blind and am unsure of how to use some of these. I've done some woodworking, but not enough to be able to make a square hole. My second thought would be to create a sort of box around a post; the post would measure the dementions of the bed posts and the box would cover the whole thing; I could then just put in scrues to hold the whole thing together. Before I go that route, are there any solutions and/or ideas? I'd have to find a hardware store willing to cut the wood to the specifications and none in Boston or at least in my area seemed willing to do so. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Bring in a handyman or retired carpenter to help you. This should not be a really complicated problem and they should have all the required tools to get this worked out.

Comment: My second thought is that if the floor is truly four inches out of level across the width of the bed I think you should really really be thinking about your personal safety and be moving to a place that has real floors that work in a level manner.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. If you put a little time into formatting your question (e.g. paragraphs) you'll be more likely to get a good answer.